# ¿Cómo concatenar criterios en "Valor de Búsqueda" de BUSCARV?

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo, formulas, formato-condicional

Tengo que utilizar la función BUSCARV en un Formato condicional que se repetirá en varios miles de celdas, por lo que no puedo dar una ubicación específica sino relativa, para poder pegar el mismo Formato Condicional en todas las celdas.

Inicialmente, esta fórmula con un Valor_Búsqueda (C3&B5), funciona, y la celda se pone del color asignado:

```
=BUSCARV(C3&B5;INDIRECTO("Actividades Diarias!$B$2:$E");3;FALSO)=INDIRECTO("OBRAS!$B$2")
```

Pero... Reemplacé, localizando las celdas con los comandos FILA y COLUMNA, la concatenación de "C3&B5" por:

```
CONCATENAR(BUSCARV(COLUMNA();INDIRECTO("Datos Auxiliares!A2:B32");2;FALSO);"3")& CONCATENAR("B";(FILA()))
```

Y el resultado es que la función BUSCARV no encuentra el valor "C3&B5", es decir que lo busca como texto (yo creo)...

```
=BUSCARV(CONCATENAR(BUSCARV(COLUMNA();INDIRECTO("Datos Auxiliares!A2:B32");2;FALSO);"3")& CONCATENAR("B";(FILA()));INDIRECTO("Actividades Diarias!$B$2:$E");3;FALSO)=INDIRECTO("OBRAS!$B$2")
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que lo interprete como la concatenación de dos celdas?

Comment: Bienvenido Diego para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por la comunidad te invito a lee [ask]

Comment: Si las celdas a las que vas a aplicar el formato condicional son consecutivas no es necesario hacer algo como lo que estas intentando ya que la herramientas es "inteligente". Agrega más detalles sobre las celdas a las que aplicarás el formato condicional para estar seguros si se puede sacar provecho de esto o no.